# Substitute Values in String Without Spaces in Helm - unexpected unclosed action in command

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Right now, I am using helm to substitute variables in a file using values from my `values.yaml` file to create a ConfigMap which is working well for entries that are spaced correctly.

I am having a problem with the following:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://admin:admin@{{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_HOST }}:5672/"
```

Results in this error when running `helm install`:

```
Error: render error in "mynamespace-nonprod-chart/templates/configmap.yaml": template: mynamespace-nonprod-chart/templates/configmap.yaml:10:4: executing "mynamespace-nonprod-chart/templates/configmap.yaml" at <tpl (.Files.Glob "conf/*").AsConfig .>: error calling tpl: Error during tpl function execution for "settings.py: \"\\\"\\\"\\\"\\nDjango settings for imagegateway project.\\n\\nGenerated by 'django-admin\n  startproject' using Django 1.11.3.\\n\\nFor more information on this file, see\\nhttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/\\n\\nFor\n  the full list of settings and their values, see\\nhttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/\\n\\\"\\\"\\\"\\n\\nimport\n  os\\n\\nfrom kombu import Exchange, Queue\\n\\n\\n# Image Config\\nIMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO\n  = (4,3) # 4:3\\nMLS_BASE_URL = 'http://www.torontomls.net/MLSMULTIPHOTOS/FULL'\\nCALLBACK_KEY\n  = 'SECRET'\\n\\nBASE_URL = 'https://media-dev.mydomain.ca'\\n\\n#\n  Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)\\nBASE_DIR\n  = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))\\n\\nMAXIMUM_HASH_DISTANCE\n  = 5\\n\\n# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!\\nSECRET_KEY\n  = 'mysecretkey'\\n\\n# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!\\n#\n  DEBUG = False\\nDEBUG = True\\n\\nALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', '*']\\n\\n# Celery\\n\\n#\n  {{ .Values.env.INGRESS_CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT }} TEST this\\nCELERY_BROKER_URL = \\\"amqp://admin:xWQ7ye7YotNif@{{\n  .Values.env.RABBITMQ_HOST }}:5672/\\\"\\nCELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']\\nCELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER\n  = 'json'\\nCELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'\\nCELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://dummyuser:R3dis0nEKS!@redis-imagegateway-dev-shared-headless'\\nCELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT\n  = False\\nCELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Canada/Eastern'\\nCELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False  \\nCELERY_ACKS_LATE\n  = True  \\nCELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1\\nCELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY = True  \\nCELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS\n  = False\\nCELERY_IMPORTS = ('garden.tasks', 'keeper.tasks', 'tourist.tasks',)\\nCELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE\n  = 'default'\\nCELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic'\\nCELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY\n  = 'default'\\nCELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60\\n\\nCELERY_TASK_QUEUES = (\\n    Queue('tourist',\n  Exchange('tourist'), routing_key='tourist.#', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority':\n  1}),\\n    Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority':\n  5}),\\n    Queue('garden', Exchange('garden'), routing_key='garden.#', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority':\n  10}),\\n    Queue('keeper', Exchange('keeper'), routing_key='keeper.#', queue_arguments={'x-max-priority':\n  10}),\\n)\\n\\nCELERY_TASK_ROUTES = {\\n     'garden.tasks.fetch_mls_image' : {'queue':\n  'garden'},\\n     'garden.tasks.save_image' : {'queue': 'garden'},\\n     'garden.tasks.do_callback'\n  : {'queue': 'garden'},\\n     'garden.tasks.clear_cloudflare_cache' : {'queue': 'garden'},\\n\n  \\    'tourist.tasks.get_fetcher' : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n     'tourist.tasks.get_tour_urls'\n  : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n     'tourist.tasks.download_tour_images' : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n\n  \\    'tourist.tasks.smallest_image_size' : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n     'tourist.tasks.hash_and_compare'\n  : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n     'tourist.tasks.process_tours' : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n\n  \\    'tourist.tasks.all_done' : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n     'tourist.tasks.save_hd_images'\n  : {'queue': 'tourist'},\\n     'keeper.tasks.create_sizes' : {'queue': 'keeper'},\\n\n  \\    'celery_tasks.debug_task': {'queue': 'default'},\\n}\\n\\n# Application definition\\n\\nINSTALLED_APPS\n  = [\\n    # Project\\n    'celery',\\n    'garden', # deals with retrieval of images\\n\n  \\   'keeper', # deals with resizing and image processing tasks\\n    'tourist', #\n  deals with virtual tours\\n    # Vendor Packages\\n    'djangocms_admin_style',\\n\n  \\   # Django\\n    'django.contrib.admin',\\n    'django.contrib.auth',\\n    'django.contrib.contenttypes',\\n\n  \\   'django.contrib.sessions',\\n    'django.contrib.messages',\\n    'django.contrib.staticfiles',\\n]\\n\\nMIDDLEWARE\n  = [\\n    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',\\n    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',\\n\n  \\   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',\\n    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',\\n\n  \\   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',\\n    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',\\n\n  \\   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',\\n]\\n\\nROOT_URLCONF\n  = 'imagegateway.urls'\\n\\nTEMPLATES = [\\n    {\\n        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',\\n\n  \\       'DIRS': ['templates'],\\n        'APP_DIRS': True,\\n        'OPTIONS': {\\n\n  \\           'context_processors': [\\n                'django.template.context_processors.debug',\\n\n  \\               'django.template.context_processors.request',\\n                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',\\n\n  \\               'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',\\n            ],\\n\n  \\       },\\n    },\\n]\\n\\nWSGI_APPLICATION = 'imagegateway.wsgi.application'\\n\\n\\n#\n  Database\\n\\nDATABASES = {\\n    'default': {\\n        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',\\n\n  \\       'NAME': 'imagegateway',\\n        'USER': 'postgres',\\n        'PASSWORD':\n  'PostGresQL123',\\n        'HOST': 'postgresql-imagegateway-dev-shared-headless',\\n\n  \\       'PORT': 5432,\\n    }\\n}\\n\\n\\n# Password validation\\n\\nAUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS\n  = [\\n    {\\n        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',\\n\n  \\   },\\n    {\\n        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',\\n\n  \\   },\\n    {\\n        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',\\n\n  \\   },\\n    {\\n        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',\\n\n  \\   },\\n]\\n\\n\\n# Internationalization\\n\\nLANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'\\n\\nTIME_ZONE =\n  'UTC'\\n\\nUSE_I18N = True\\n\\nUSE_L10N = True\\n\\nUSE_TZ = True\\n\\n\\n# Static files\n  (CSS, JavaScript, Images)\\n\\nSTATIC_URL = '/static/'\\nSTATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,\n  'static/')\\n\\n\\n# Media files (Images)\\n\\nMEDIA_URL = '/media/'\\n\\n# Controls whether\n  Keras and backend is imported every server restart to improve restart times\\n# Only\n  set the first bool!!! Then in production when DEBUG is set to false it will default\n  to True.\\n# Example: \\n#    WITH_IMAGE_CLASSIFIER = True if DEBUG else True \\n#\n  or WITH_IMAGE_CLASSIFIER = False if DEBUG else True\\nWITH_IMAGE_CLASSIFIER = True\n  if DEBUG else True\\n\\n# 20MB\\nFILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 20971520\\nDATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE\n  = 20971520\\n\\n# Cloudflare\\nCLOUDFLARE_API_URL = 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/'\\nCLOUDFLARE_API_KEY\n  = ''\\nCLOUDFLARE_API_EMAIL = ''\\nCLOUDFLARE_ZONE_ID = ''\\n\"\n": parse error in "mynamespace-nonprod-chart/templates/configmap.yaml": template: mynamespace-nonprod-chart/templates/configmap.yaml:12: unexpected unclosed action in command
```

If I had set `env.RABBITMQ_HOST:rabbitmq.mydomain.com`, i'd expect the substituted value to be:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://admin:admin@rabbitmq.mydomain.com:5672/"
```

Values:

```
useCustomApplicatonConfigs:
  - mountPath: /var/www/html/django
    type: py
    name:
      - settings

env:
  CELERY_BROKER_URL: "amqp://admin:xWQ7ye7YotNif@rabbitmq-imagegateway-dev-shared-headless:5672"
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this? Do I need to escape the `@` or something?

Edit: Added values section.

Comment: You do not need to escape the `@`.  Might be helpful to post the relevant sections of your `values.yaml` and `configmap.yaml` because what you've posted so far should not result in an error.

Comment: In the error message you quote, it looks like there's a newline after the `{{`.  Can you double-check that in your YAML file?

Comment: @LiquidPony, I have added the `values.yaml` snippet.

Comment: @DavidMaze, interesting. I didn't have a newline in the line I wanted substituted, but I did have a comment above and when I removed it, it started to work. `# {{ .Values.env.INGRESS_CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT }} TEST this
`

Comment: This is what ended up working - `CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_USER}}:{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}}@{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_HOST}}:{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_PORT}}/"` I removed the spaces in between `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: @leeman24, Can you elaborate and finalize your solution research within an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I had to change to get my configuration to work.

The first issue was that I was using a yaml comments vs. a template comment which tried to get substituted when running `helm install` so I removed it completely. I should have been using {{- /* This is a comment. */ -}} according to the helm documentation instead of #.

The second issue was with the spaces between the curly braces `{{` and `}}`.

Before:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://{{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_USER }}:{{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD }}@{{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_HOST }}:{{ .Values.env.RABBITMQ_PORT }}/"
```

After (working):

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_USER}}:{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}}@{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_HOST}}:{{.Values.env.RABBITMQ_PORT}}/"
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure why helm didn't like the spaces between curly braces but wanted to post an answer. If someone could comment on that, i'm sure it'll be helpful for myself and others.